# HttpClient using Basic authentication

Tags: c#, wpf, httpclient

Hi i am trying to call basic authentication in wpf httpclient. however whenever i run the code nothing is showing. Can someone help me why? I am new. Thank you

This is the code:

```
            var userName = "username";
            var passwd = "password";

            var url = "url";

            using var client = new HttpClient();

            var authToken = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{userName}:{passwd}");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
            AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                    Convert.ToBase64String(authToken));

            var result = await client.GetAsync(url);

            var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            label1.Content = content;
```

Comment: It looks like you're not checking the status of the response at the moment. I suggest you call `result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` before reading the content.

Comment: I tried printing result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() I got StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:

Comment: Okay, so that sounds promising. And have you run this in the debugger to check the value of the `content` variable, in case this is actually a UI issue?

Answer (score 1):

Add content type json since you are returning json. And you have to deserialize your content after receiving

```
   var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
    var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var stringData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(stringData);
        // instead of object it is better to use a class you are expecting from request
    } else ...error
```